# How to discover the IP(s) of the backend service(s) an app on my cellphone is consuming through my linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I want to discover the IP or URLs of the backend service(s) the food delivery app on my cellphone consumes, so I can add it to the blocklist of my router and stop using it on impulse (don't ask).

I don't have much knowledge in networks, I assumed the app consumes some kind of backend and it's possible to monitor my network traffic through my desktop. I was thinking about navigating/opening and closing the app a lot of times and watching if some IP appears repeatedly.

I'm using ubuntu, if there's any native unix tool that would be perfect, but I don't mind installing 3rd party apps.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to discover the IP or URLs of the backend service(s) the food delivery app on my cellphone consumes

Make an access point on Ubuntu, have your cell phone connect to this access point, use something like `wireshark` or `mitmproxy` to sniff traffic when you use the food delivery app. You'll see both the URLs and the IP addresses.

You can block either by configuring the DNS services on your router (best way, if your router can do that, or if you install something like OpenWRT where you can do that), or you can block the IP addresses. But be aware that if the app uses some cloud bases services, the IP addresses will likely be shared by lots of other services, and they also can change randomly, so this is an unreliable method.

> I don't have much knowledge in networks

Then expect to spend quite a bit of time in experiments and reading network stuff until you can make the above work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can start mitmproxy on your computer and then go into your phone's Wi-Fi settings and set your phone to use your computer as an explicit proxy.

Comment: Thank you very much!